# Use windows update for my application

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-update

Does anyone know of a way to register (using code of course) my application to windows update, so it will check the for updates using their update application ?

Thanks

Comment: If you publish using ClickOnce that will update when the user starts your application. Other installers probably do the same too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Update (and Microsoft Update) will only update the OS and its components (and other products from Microsoft).